# Multiple ssl configuration on different ports

Tags: apache-2.4

I have been searching this for some time and couldn't get to a speicifc answer.
I have configured a sever in CentOS env, with the following configuration in my vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /xyz/dir
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    CustomLog /var/log/xyz/access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/xyz/error.log
    <Directory /xyz/dir>
        Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:83>
    DocumentRoot /abc/dir
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    CustomLog /var/log/abc/access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/abc/error.log
    <Directory /abc/dir>
        Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I have configured 2 sites on different ports with same ip. Now I am trying to configure ssl on both the sites, I want the http as well as https both activated simultaneously on both.

I did some search and configured it with ssl, and added the following :-

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+SSLv3
    SSLCACertificateFile /path-to-ca-bundle
    SSLCertificateFile /path-to-crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile path-to-key
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    DocumentRoot /xyz/dir
    ServerName 1.1.1.1:80
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    CustomLog /var/log/xyz/access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/xyz/error.log
    <Directory /xyz/dir>
        Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Did the same for :83
```

Now this works fine when I hit

```
https://1.1.1.1/ --> points to xyz
http://1.1.1.1/ --> points to xyz

http://1.1.1.1:83/ --> points to abc
https://1.1.1.1:83/ --> throws ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error
```

The https on :83 is not working. Need help !

Also `https://1.1.1.1:80/ --> throws ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error`
On the contrary `https://1.1.1.1/ --> works just fine and points to xyz`

Comment: You have picked port 443 to provide an https version of the http service on port 80. I can't tell what port you've picked to offer the https equivalent of the http service on port 83, and it looks somewhat as if you've tried to run them both on the same port (83), which won't work.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, practically speaking, have both a HTTP and a HTTPS service running on the same port.  That is why the default ports for both protocols are different (80 and 443, respectively).  This means that your service on port 83 can be *either* HTTP *or* HTTPS, but not both.  You'll need to pick a separate port to be available for the other protocol.